# StreamReader Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, sql, nullreferenceexception, streamreader

Im trying to read SQL statement from .SQL files in a resource folder, 
I have 2 .SQL files right now and it reads one correctly and the other returns a `NullRefrenceException`

Here is my calling of the sql files:

```
 string sqlFailRecordNoMatch = EmbeddedResource.GetString("Resources.SQLScripts.RecordNumberFailQuery.sql");
```

Here is the `GetString` method:

```
public static string GetString(System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, string name)
{
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = EmbeddedResource.GetStream(assembly, name);
    string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: On the second .SQL file have you stepped through in debug and checked the value of `data`?  My guess is that it is null for some reason.

Comment: Well if one reads correctly, it's not an issue with the code to read it, but more likely finding the file.

Comment: Are you showing a different overload of GetString? The one above takes an assembly as first parameter but you call a GetString with only a string parameter

Comment: Most likely, you have a typo in your name parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason you would get a `NullReferenceException` on one vs. the other is:

1. The one that's failing isn't set as an `Embedded Resource`. You can check that by clicking on the file in the `Solution Explorer` and hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>.
2. You're using the wrong fully qualified path.

I suspect it's #1.

Comment: Thank you! It was the first one. Such a simple mistake, it would have taken me ages to find that.

Comment: @user2056726, no worries friend. I only know this because I've done it myself!

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you simply use the resource editor from Visual Studio:

- Within your project create a new folder (maybe called *Queries*)
- Right click this folder and select Add - New Item
- In the dialog just select `Textfile` and give it the name about what this query will do

  - Make sure you replace the file extension from `.txt` to  `.sql`
- Just put your statement right into this file
- In the Resource Editor add this file as a resource (normally located in your project under the properties folder or simply also create it by Add - New Item - Resources File)
- Now you can access this sql statement within your code just by using `Properties.Resources.MySqlStatement`